# Color of every pixel in a photo in python

Tags: python

I'm getting into Python Coding and I really want to make an code that shows me the color of every Pixel of an image. Can someone help me code this?

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:

First we try to import and get image data

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('example.png')
imgWidth, imgHeight = img.size
img = img.convert("RGBA")
imgdata = img.getdata()

x_pos = 0
y_pos = 1

pixel_value = []
x = []
y = []
```

Then do an iteration based on image width and store pixels data:

```
for item in imgdata:
    #if we reached the shape's width, go to the next row
    if (x_pos) == imgWidth:
        x_pos = 1
        y_pos += 1
    else:
        x_pos += 1

    if item[3] != 0:
        pixel_value.append(item[2])
        x.append(x_pos)
        y.append(y_pos)

pixel_value, x, y = zip(*sorted(zip(pixel_value, x, y), reverse=True))

print(f'{pixel_value}\n{x}\n{y}')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: @Thekingis007 Added more explanations . Thanks.

Comment: Does your solution show the color of every Pixel of the image? Because when I tested it it only shows numbers not colors.

Comment: Well, colors are numbers. What seems strange to me is that it looks like you're only printing the values of the blue band. Why not print `(R, G, B)`?